# SetOnClickListener is underfined for the type TextView

Tags: android, eclipse

There is error at SetOnClickListener. It says that **The method SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type TextView** . Why?

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set View to register.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.link_to_login);

        //Listening to Login Screen Link
        loginScreen.SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                //Closing reg screen
                //Switching to Login Screen/closing reg screen
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `SetOnClickListener` should be `setOnClickListener. Method names start with lowercase in Java by convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
```

and import

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

and add @Override Annotation

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
```